# How to use scrapy-selenium to scrape javascript input

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

i am trying to modify my webcrawler, so I am able to get the information of Javascript inputs on the websites. And want to do it with selenium and not with splash. Below an example:

```
class TestSpider(Spider):
name="test"
start_urls = ["http://crawler-test.com/mobile/dynamic"]


my_excludes = ['style','link','meta','script','noscript','base']
my_str = '//text()['
for my_exclude in my_excludes:
    my_str = my_str + "not(ancestor::" + my_exclude + ") and "
my_str = my_str[:-5] + "]"

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    body = response.xpath(self.my_str).re(".*")
    file = open("TestResult.txt", "w")
    file.writelines(body)
    file.close()
    print(body)
```

I also did the changes in the settings like advised in the docu:

```
from shutil import which

BOT_NAME = 'TestSpider'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['TestSpider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'TestSpider.spiders'
 
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'

SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')

SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800}
```

I get the static input of the website but not the dynamic. (Javascript)
Some help would be very nice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just read your article, I was focusing on the same problem.

```
chk_seller_xpath = '//*/input[@id="e1-13"]'
js = "document.evaluate('%s', document, null,  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()" % chk_seller_xpath
driver.execute_script(js)
```

I could execute the script in javascript by doing the above.